# Disable button if nothing is selected in ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I've got this code to generate a ui-select:

```
<ui-select ng-model="newTask.work" theme="select2" class="form-control" title="Scegli un lavoro">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Scegli un lavoro">{{$select.selected.label}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in lavori | filter: $select.search">
                              <div ng-bind-html="item.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I would like to disable a button if this ui-select has nothing selected, but writing this doesn't work

`ng-disabled="!work"`

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what does `work` represent? it certainly doesn't represent your `ng-model`, which is `newTask.work`.

Comment: I write wrong in the question. With !newTask.work the button is always disabled, also if you choose something in ui-select.

Also with newTask.work.isEmpty() it doesn't work.

Comment: A plunkr or a jsfiddle would help :)

Comment: Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/iMkIIToSbdiOvpWuc8GB?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, a Plunkr would help.

Out of interest, does this make any difference:

```
ng-disabled="!newTask.work || newTask.work.length == 0"
```

One other tip: during development, when you hit issues like this, it's worth sticking this on your webpage:

```
<pre>{{ newTask.work | json }}</pre>
```

It'll show you the raw value of your binded Angular variable, so you can see its value change as you select/unselect items in your `<ui-select>` control.

Hope this helps.

**Update (after seeing the Plunkr):**

If you add the following lines to your script.js, you'll see that the `pre` I suggested does show the value you select in your drop down list, and from there, you can set your `ng-disabled` flag:

```
  $scope.newTask =
  { 
      work: null
  };
```

... and your button will become enabled when you select an item in your drop down list.

(This is why I recommend the `pre` idea..  it showed nothing in your Plunkr, even after selecting an item, immediately showing that your Angular variable wasn't bound to the select, or didn't exist.)

Comment: This is the Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/iMkIIToSbdiOvpWuc8GB?p=preview

The <pre> is always empty.

Comment: PS: The <pre> is populated only if first I write something in the input text.
If I change the select, write something and then change again it nothing appears, but if FIRST AL ALL I write something and then I change the select, it works. I don't know why.

Comment: ... Because you hadn't created a "newTask" variable.  See my comment above.   This is all you needed to add.

Comment: But I'm italian! Ahah